# Mongodb sum by field exists

Tags: mongodb, sum

I have the following collection with the number of fields changing over time.

```
{ 
    "_id" : "9235@7421",
    "usine" : { "0" : 0, "1" : 3, "2" : 1, "3" : 2, "4" : 0, "5" : 3, "6" : 1, "7" : 0, "8" : 2, "9" : 1 }, 
    "ecole" : { "0" : 1, "1" : 0, "2" : 0, "3" : 1, "4" : 1, "5" : 0, "6" : 0, "7" : 1, "8" : 0, "9" : 1 }
}
```

The following query works fine. It calculates the sum of the values of all fields.

```
db.lieux.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "_id": "9235@7421"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "MontoSum": {
                $sum: {
                    $add: [
                        "$usine.0", "$usine.1", "$usine.2", "$usine.3", "$usine.4", "$usine.5", "$usine.6", "$usine.7", "$usine.8", "$usine.9", "$ecole.0", "$ecole.1", "$ecole.2", "$ecole.3", "$ecole.4", "$ecole.5", "$ecole.6", "$ecole.7", "$ecole.8", "$ecole.9"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The result is: `{ "_id" : "9235@7421", "MontoSum" : 18 }`  and this is correct.

My questions are :

1) is there a better way to query the sum of values of the fields of my collection? I feel that my query is too long and not smart at all.

2) When a document is missing a field that is in my query (for example field "6" is missing), the returned value is { "_id" : "9235@7421", "MontoSum" : 0 }   which is not correct. It seems to me that the sum function does not like missing fields. How can I use someting like $ifNull in my case?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We can use operators like [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to manipulate object structure:

```
{
    $project: {
        "MontoSum": {
            $sum: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    {
                        $map: {
                            input: {$objectToArray: "$usine"},
                            as: "usine",
                            in: "$$usine.v"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $map: {
                            input: {$objectToArray: "$ecole"},
                            as: "ecole",
                            in: "$$ecole.v"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this isn't exactly the shortest expression but it scales.

2. Using these operators will also fix this issue as you were summing an undefined value caused that unexpected behaviour.